# Replacing Widget in Flutter with use of Provider

Tags: flutter, provider, consumer

I am using Provider state management in my Flutter app project.
Actually, Its OTP screen which is divided in to to Widget:

1. Enter Phone Number Widget,
2. Enter OTP widget.

I can't replace my second widget once user enteres Phone number and click on 'Send' button.
Below is my OTP Screen you can check:

```
Expanded(
child: Consumer(
    builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget? child) {
    return ResponsiveHelperWidget(
        mobile: viewModel.isPhoneNumberEntered
            ? fillPhoneNumberWidget
            : otpVerificationWidget,
        desktop: Row(
        children: [
            const Expanded(child: OTPWebPageFillerWidget()),
            Expanded(child: fillPhoneNumberWidget),
        ],
        ),
    );
    },
),
)
```

Here, you can check this line:

```
viewModel.isPhoneNumberEntered
                    ? fillPhoneNumberWidget
                    : otpVerificationWidget,
```

That is the way I am trying to replace my widget.

You can check my ViewModel as below:

```
class OTPViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
    http.Client client = http.Client();
    var isPhoneNumberEntered = false;
    OTPViewModel() {
    //pending..
    }
      
    final TextEditingController phoneC = TextEditingController();
    final TextEditingController otpC = TextEditingController();
      
    set setPhoneNumberEntered(bool value) {
    isPhoneNumberEntered = value;
    notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Here you can check the setter `setPhoneNumberEntered` where I am changing the value and notifying the listener.

Calling this setter as below in my first widget as below:

```
onPressed: () {                                     
    widget.viewModel.setPhoneNumberEntered = true;
                },
```

But the issue is my second widget (Enter OTP Widget) is not being visible.

What I am doing wrong here? Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a silly mistake:

Have to replace this:

```
desktop: Row(
          children: [
            const Expanded(child: OTPWebPageFillerWidget()),
            Expanded(child: fillPhoneNumberWidget),
          ],
        ),
```

with this:

```
desktop: Row(
                children: [
                  const Expanded(child: OTPWebPageFillerWidget()),
                  Expanded(
                      child: value.isPhoneNumberEntered
                          ? otpVerificationWidget
                          : fillPhoneNumberWidget),
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you have to use valuenotifier

```
class OTPViewModel{
…
ValueNotifier<bool> isPhoneNumberEntered = ValueNotifier(false);

…
```

//you onpressed like this

```
onPressed: () {
  viewModel.setPhoneNumberEntered.value = true;
  viewModel.setPhoneNumberEntered.notifyListeners();
},
```

//and your widget should like this,

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: viewModel.isPhoneNumberEntered,
    builder: (context,isPhoneNumberEnteredValue,child){

      return ResponsiveHelperWidget(
        mobile: isPhoneNumberEnteredValue
            ? fillPhoneNumberWidget
            : otpVerificationWidget,
        desktop: Row(
          children: [
            const Expanded(child: OTPWebPageFillerWidget()),
            Expanded(child: fillPhoneNumberWidget),
          ],
        ),
      );

    }
),
```

Comment: Can you please also guide for the setter I am using: setPhoneNumberEntered ? Is it okay? because it saying me 'The getter setPhoneNumerEntered' isn't defined for the type 'OTPViewModel'

Comment: Ohh my god, the issue was the only the last line also I need to change...with conditional argument ? :  and the issue is solved with consumer it self